# BRDFs in 3D Rendering

Tags: graphics, 3d, rendering, shader

I'm reading [this](http://renderwonk.com/publications/s2010-shading-course/hoffman/s2010_physically_based_shading_hoffman_a_notes.pdf) famous article and I can't seem to understand the BRDF concept, especially the bold part:

> The surface’s response to light is quantified by a function called the
>   BRDF (Bidirectional Reflectance Distribution Function), which we will
>   denote as f(l, v). **Each direction (incoming and outgoing) can be
>   parameterized with two numbers (e.g. polar coordinates), so the
>   overall dimensionality of the BRDF is four.**

To which directions is the author referring? Also, if this is 3d, then how can a direction be parameterized with two numbers and not three?

Comment: To lazy to read the article so can not help with what directions are meant by that (most likely directions to light source, to observer) but in spherical coordinate system (where object or surface is centered) you need just 2 angles to determine **3D** direction (radius is constant  `r = 1` ). You can look at it as a geo position longitude ,latitude points to some position on sphere surface and the direction is from center to that point (so does not matter what radius the sphere is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A BRDF describes the light reflectance characteristics of a surface. For every pair of incoming (l) and outgoing (v) directions, the BRDF tells you how much light will be reflected along v. Since we are in surface space, two polar coordinates are sufficient to define the entire hemisphere over the reflection point. The following image from [anu.edu.au](http://escience.anu.edu.au/lecture/cg/GlobalIllumination/BRDF.en.html) illustrates this concept:

[image: Illustration of the parameterization of a BRDF]